# Как убрать повторы из строки?

Tags: python

У меня есть строка `AAAABBBCCDAABBB`.

Мне нужно сделать так, что бы значение не повторялось два раза подряд. То есть - вывести что то на подобии `"A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B"`

Я пробовал

```
lst = []



for i in 'AAAABBBCCDAABBB':
    if i not in 'AAAABBBCCDAABBB':
        lst.append(i)

return lst
```

Но получилось что то непонятное. Как подобное реализовать?

Comment: используйте set()

Comment: Сравниваем текущий символ с предыдущим. Если отличаются, добавляем в массив

Comment: set() уберет все повторения из строки. А мне надо что бы одинаковые символы не шли подряд, а не что бы они были в единичном экземпляре

Comment: Если писать код наугад, а не подумав предварительно, то обычно и получается "что то непонятное".

Answer (score 3):

```
sequence = 'AAAABBBCCDAABBB'


abc = []
abc.append(sequence[0])

for i in sequence:
    if i != abc[-1]:
        abc.append(i)
return abc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools


print([k for k, _ in itertools.groupby('AAAABBBCCDAABBB')])
```

> ```
> ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B']
> ```